# JavaFX webview swipe scrolling on touch screen

Tags: swing, scroll, webview, javafx, touchscreen

I'm using a `JavaFX` webview inside my `Swing` application. I would like to be able to scroll the content of the WebView on touch enabled screens by swiping the finger.

However, if I do so, the content of the website gets selected, but no scrolling happens.

In `Swing` I implemented a swipe scrolling by adding listeners to Mouse Events and then animating the scrolling. But since the touch event inside WebView happens inside the (webkit) html engine, I think I cannot react on these events other than via JavaScript.

Is there another way to enable touch scrolling in `JavaFX` webview? Or is there a simple JavaScript library, which enables touch scrolling on a HTML/JavaScript level (like google is doing it for google maps)?

I'd appreciate any hint. Thanks